# React render instagram feeds from data.json

Tags: reactjs

I"m trying to render username comments with likes and a like. *please see image on demo*.

- All of this comes form data.json

I can't  find a way to display the json properly on the tags. What am I missing here?

*Sorry I'm trying my best here with react as I'm quite a beginner.*

**[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-semantic-ui-forked-fjnce?file=/src/app/children/posts/index.js:108-454)**

**my index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./styles";
import { getCaptionFromEdges } from "./helpers";

const Posts = (props) => {
  const { data } = props;
  return (

   <img src={data.owner.profile_pic_url} /> // this tag works
   <p>{data.owner.node.username}</p> // this tag doesn't work
   
   <hr>


   //here I should display all comments with its like.
   <p>{data.node.text}</p>// this doesn't work



      
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your elements with another element (or a Fragment). Try the following:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./styles";
import { getCaptionFromEdges } from "./helpers";

const Posts = (props) => {
  const { data } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <img src={data.owner.profile_pic_url} />
      <p>{data.owner.node.username}</p>
   
      <hr />

      <p>{data.node.text}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

Comment: thanks but did you check my demo? this doesn't work.  you can fork it  if you want to try.

Comment: You should be more specific. [Krzysztof Woliński](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8798840/krzysztof-woli%c5%84ski) pointed out an issue you had regardless of the actual reason your code may not work. It will definitely help to give more information, i.e. - what exactly doesn't work, are there console errors, is the console clean and the data is not rendering, etc.. As well as any other information you can provide that could help identify the problem you're having.